# Collapsing toolbar title ignores textStyle and fontStyle while expanded

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've got a couple of toolbars. The upper one's id is `toolbar2` and the second one's id is `toolbar`. They are both placed within `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The upper toolbar got: `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` and the second one – `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`.

I set the same text appearance for both of them, but `toolbar` doesn't get bold and most likely hasn't got the `fontFamily` I specified. It only gets the right `textColor` and `textSize` from the following style, while the upper toolbar has got all the parameters as I specified:

```
<style name="ToolbarTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

So, I wanted the same text appearance for both toolbars, though, here is what I've got:

[image]

Can somebody please tell me why that behaviour appears and how I can get the behaviour I want?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTextAppearance"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="18dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTextAppearance">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="Toolbar 2"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTextAppearance" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="Toolbar"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTextAppearance" />

            <RelativeLayout
                ...
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`targetSdkVersion` is 27

Comment: If you ever found an answer I am curious to know more...